# win 8 app multi threading

Tags: multithreading, windows-8

I have an win8 app and I want to add proggress ring while app gets info from server.
but when 
proggressRing.isActivate = true;
checkServer();

the app freezes until returns from checkServer() and proggressRing does not activates when it freezes.
I asked around and said you have to use multi threading
how can I use multi thread in c# or is there any other way?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions to this
1) first ensure that CheckServer is implemented as Async Task (Async Event based can still be used).

2) If it is CPU intensive operation, use Task.Run to queue the Task to run on a threadpool thread.

have a look at this post
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452713.aspx and this one 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: actually I only work on xaml and on the parts where the elements in the xaml needs to be added my c# knowledge is limited 
I read the 2nd link and the example is similar to my case
but nothing will return from the async function
user enters id and clicks a button then the id will be checked in the server with another method (thats where it freezes) and multiple information returns I cannot change so much in that code I'm not allowed to. What I want is when user clicks a progrress ring appear and dissappear when the infos return

Comment: well the problem is that you are executing the code in UI thread. that is the reason why the progress ring does not appear. you can of course create a event / task based async call within your code rather than modifying CheckServer method itself